# Allow any order between grammar rules including optional ones in ANTLR4

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

I have a rule defined like this:

```
rule: ( a | b | c | d | e )*;
```

I do this expression because I want to allow **any** ordering of the individual grammar objects - with no assumptions whatsoever.

But now, I would like to express that rule `a` for example is optional, but the rest is not. If I write

```
rule: ( a? | b | c | d | e )*;
```

then of course this could match the empty string which I don't want.
I want that there is always at least one `b`, `c`, `d`, or `e` present and *one or no* `a`.

Comment: You need two lookaheads: [`^(?=.*[bcde])(?!(?:.*a){2})`](https://regex101.com/r/6qnFGD/1).

Comment: ANTLR rules bear some resemblance to Regex, but, most definitely, are NOT Regexs

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're `*` cardinality, means that ALL of them are optional, and `rule` can match empty input.

Change the `*` to a `+`:

```
rule: ( a | b | c | d | e )+;
```

This will require one or more of the options (and allows for them to occur multiple times).

Since you want to allow for any order, this really the most specific you can be in your grammar.

Many of us would say that the main goal of a grammar is to specify in an unambiguous way, the only possible way to interpret (aka, parse) the input.  That is, it should cover the syntactic concerns.

From there, you can follow up in either visitors or, more likely, listeners, to encode the semantic concerns, like "You must have a `b`, a `c`, a `d`, an `e`, and may optionally have an `a`"

Also, understand that, by handling this in your own validation in a listener, you have the ability to craft a much more meaningful error message, than what ANTLR would be able to craft, even if you could capture all of those rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the grammar:

```
optional : a ; 
required : b | c | d | e ;
rule: optional* required (required|optional)*;
```